# Activation or Registration of My App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I want to make an activity in my app which should only come until the correct activation or registration code is entered.
How can I implement that? With IMEI of device? and how to code so that it does not comes again after a successful registration?

Comment: One thing to consider when tying activation to the IMEI is that users will expect to be able to use your app on more than one device. Users may lose / break / upgrade their device regularly, or own both a handset and a tablet for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can associate the registration code with an IMEI for uniqueness purposes but you will have to do it on your own server in order to avoid any security cheats.

As for it never coming again, you have 2 options:

1. On every application launch, you query your server with the IMEI and check if the code was successfully entered, then do not  display the activity
2. Save it (advisably as encrypted locally in a file) (Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html))